Identifying and Using Different Fonts
New to Latex here. Could you please advise on how to load different kinds of fonts, instead of the regular/default one? Anybody could guide me on how to use it by myself? I checked on i2pdf.com and identify the font as "ArnoPro".


Welcome to TeX.SE!

If you have "Adobe Acrobat Professional, then open the PDF file through AdobeAcrobat, and you can find the used fonts by press Ctrl+D`

most pdf viewers will tell you which fonts are used in a pdf e.g. okular tells me this in one tab of a pop-up detailing document properties. you certainly don't need commercial software. or you can use e.g. pdffonts which is part of poppler if you're using linux, a bsd-based os or mac etc. I think, but am not certain, this also applies to windows. (inkscape depends on poppler on linux and inkscape works on windows, but it is always possible it uses something other than poppler there.)

https://www.tug.org/FontCatalogue/ is a good place to start. note that you've tagged this with incompatible tags i.e. you cannot use fontspec with pdftex or metafont. (but you don't want to use metafont unless you are producing hard copy only and, even then, you don't want the restrictions if you can help it.)
